# Spring boot SOAP service running in docker doesn't find ExtensibilityElement class

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, soap, wsdl

I'm setting up a SOAP service using spring-boot and run it in a docker container.
When I run the jar alone everything works fine, but when I try to run it in a docker container it fail to initialize and throws this error:

```
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.Wsdl11Definition]: Factory method 'defaultWsdl11Definition' threw exception; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/wsdl/extensions/ExtensibilityElement
```

I already try different images, also creating a base docker image and install oracle jdk manually.

You can find the exact code [here](https://github.com/Gueka/docker-soap.git) and try by yourself.

To run the app:

```
gradle build
java -jar build/libs/service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

To create the docker image:

```
docker build -t soap:service --build-arg JAR_FILE=./build/libs/service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .
```

To run the docker image:

```
docker run soap:service
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone wants to know, the problem was that wsdl4j library was setted to be on compileOnly and by changing it to compile the library was presented on the final jar.

For more information visit https://community.liferay.com/blogs/-/blogs/gradle-compile-vs-compileonly-vs-compileinclude